# How to define a constant in a Matlab class?

Tags: matlab, class, enums

I'd like to create a Matlab enumeration class with a method to look up values from a table based on the corresponding numerical values to each enumeration. Here's what I've got:

```
classdef testclass < uint8
    enumeration
        enum1 (1)
        enum2 (2)
        enum3 (3)
    end

    A = [100 200 300;101 202 303;111 222 333];

    methods
        function retval = getval(obj1,obj2)
            retval = testclass.A(obj1,obj2);
        end
    end
end
```

So far, I've tried:

- Not inheriting properties from uint8 and adding a `properties` block to the class with the matrix A, which I'd like to be constant, and a property B, which I'd like to be the number corresponding to each enum. I get an error saying the first enum (presumably each of the others too) has too many arguments in its definition.
- The code above. I get an error at the line containing A saying it's an unexpected MATLAB expression.
- Not inheriting properties from uint8 and adding two `properties` blocks, since I would think Matlab would expect two arguments for each enum definition if I define two properties. The first `properties` block is Constant, the second doesn't have anything after "properties." This doesn't work either.
- Defining the matrix A inside the `getval` function. This works, but I'd like A to be available to other methods within the class.

How can I define a variable that's available to each method in the class?

Comment: You should explain and give example of use case: how you would like to call the class and what should be the resulting output. You explained what you tried but not much what you want as a result, and it not exactly clear at the moment.

Comment: @Hoki I'd like to be able to define two variables, say `a=testclass.enum1` and `b=testclass.enum3`. I would then like to be able to call the getval function, which looks up a value in A at the index (a,b), which would be equivalent to A(1,3) in this case. The function should return the value at A(1,3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot define properties on an enumeration class that is inherited.  You could instead define a function over your enumeration class (such as 'double') which would return some underlying value.  Then you can use this value to reference a constant.  Please see the following example:

class:

```
classdef testclass
    enumeration
        enum1
        enum2
        enum3
    end
    properties(Constant)
        A = [100 200 300;101 202 303;111 222 333];
    end
    methods
        function retval = getval(obj1,obj2)
            retval = testclass.A(double(obj1),double(obj2));
        end
        function retval = double(obj)
            if obj == testclass.enum1
                retval = 1;
            elseif obj == testclass.enum2
                retval = 2;
            elseif obj == testclass.enum3
                retval = 3;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

to run:

```
A = testclass.enum1
B = testclass.enum2
getval(A,B)
```

Comment: This works, and is probably the best way to do it. My solution/kludge was to create a class that was not inherited, then define a static method for each constant that took no arguments and just returned the value of the constant. The getval method checks to see if the matrix A is loaded from a mat file, and if not, loads it and returns the value at the corresponding index.

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with your code.

1. I don't know if this is important or not, depending on your values in A, but you cannot represent numbers over 255 with uint8; as in 300, 303, 333.  So you need to use uint16 or smaller values inside the A matrix.
2. I don't quite see the intent of why you want to have obj1 and obj2 as inputs.  If you need two arguments, my solution will need modification.
3. Your class and constructor method should have the same name.

I think this is what you are after:

```
>> en = getval.enum1
>> en.a
ans = 
   1x3 uint16 row vector
   101 202 303
>> en.a*2
ans = 
   1x3 uint16 row vector
   202 404 606

classdef getval
    enumeration
        enum1 (1)
        enum2 (2)
        enum3 (3)
    end
    properties
        a
    end

    methods
        function retval = getval(a)            
            A = uint16([100 200 300;101 202 303;111 222 333]);
            retval.a = A(a,:);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: A in my use case was actually a cell array containing strings, and since I needed fewer than a dozen enums, the use of uint8 didn't pose a problem. The getval method does require two arguments because there are two indices that have to be referenced to return the string stored in a single cell. Your third point was one of the key things I was missing; to me it seems redundant to have to define a constructor method inside a class definition, but I guess it allows you to define other class properties (like a constant) that don't have to be set when declaring each enumeration.

Comment: @zaen So you don't have a requirement that the returned variable by a uint8?  If you want to return a string, why didn't you include that in your example?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
>> en = getval.enum1
>> en.A
ans = 
   1x3 uint16 row vector
   101 202 303
>> en.A*2
ans = 
   1x3 uint16 row vector
   202 404 606

classdef getval
    enumeration
        enum1 (100,200,300)
        enum2 (101,202,303)
        enum3 (111,222,333)
    end
    properties
        A
    end
    methods
        function retval = getval(a,b,c)            
            retval.A = uint16([a,b,c]);
        end
    end
end
```